# JSON file corrupted after device reboot

Tags: android, json

I am persisting objects with JSON. When I create some objects, exit and relaunch the app, the file is read correctly and the objects are deserialized as expected. However, if I reboot the device after creating the objects and try to relaunch the app, the JSON file is corrupted and the app crashes. Using the debugger, I see that the reader is reading only � characters. If I go into the app info and reset the data, the app launches correctly.

I'm converting instances of my object into `JSONObjects` and storing them into a `JSONArray` before writing its `toString()` value to file:

```
public final void saveItems(@NonNull List<T> items) throws IOException {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (T item : items) {
            array.put(item.toJsonObject());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(mContext.openFileOutput(mFilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        writer.write(array.toString());
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I read the file:

```
public final List<T> loadItems() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = mContext.openFileInput(mFilename);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        // Crashes here!
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString.toString()).nextValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            items.add(newItem(array.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
    return items;
}
```

The reader is only reading �s, so the value of `jsonString.toString()` is not a proper JSON array string and I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
```

Comment: Try passing "UTF8" as a second param to OutputStreamWriter(). and InputStreamReader().

Comment: @michaelcarrano No luck with "UTF-8"

Comment: Can you show a sample of what your JSON looks like? Looking at the error, you have a ClassCastException which makes me believe you may be parsing things incorrectly.

Comment: @michaelcarrano `[{"id":1,"recurring_days":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false],"enabled":true,"minutes":55,"vibrates":false,"ringtone":"content:\/\/media\/internal\/audio\/media\/13","label":"","hour":13}]`. After rebooting, it's just a string with � characters like `"�������������������������"`, so even the `[` and`]` that indicates the string is a JSON array are corrupted.